# Odd Type Inference in Dynamically Typed Method

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-inference

While working on a config manager object, I wanted to implement a method that would retrieve a value from the manager's internal index and autocast it to the desired type, removing the need for an explicit cast. I figured this would be easy enough, using the generics system that Java offers in method headers. So, I structured my method as such:

```
public <T> T getSettingAutocast(String key)
    {
        T retV = null;

        try {retV = (T) getSetting(key);}catch (ClassCastException ignored){}

        return retV;
    }
```

I tested the method by using it to pull a File from the settings registry, like so:

```
File f = configIO.getSettingAutocast("file");
```

where the registry had already been preloaded with a File object at that key address.

This worked as expected. However, if I swapped the `File` for an `Integer`, things didn't go so well - I got a `ClassCastException`. Looking at it in debug mode, `T` is the proper type at the start of the method, but when the cast is called, it just morphs into whatever type was returned by `getSetting`.

I was under the impression that the compiler tried to infer `<T>` from the destination object (in this case, a `File` or an `Integer`), not any types in the method body itself. If someone could provide more insight on how the compiler deals with type inference when it comes to methods, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are still getting a `ClassCastException` propagated is that this method doesn't *actually* cast.

After type erasure, the assignment is:

```
retV = (Object) getSetting(key);
```

Which succeeds, of course, because everything is an object (unless it's primitive, but then you wouldn't be able to use generics here).

The cast is actually punted to the call site:

```
Integer = (Integer) configIO.getSettingAutocast("file");
```

(Try decompiling the code, you will see a `checkcast` instruction there).

So *that* is where the exception is thrown from, as you should note from your stack trace.

> I was under the impression...

Nope. You get exactly what you deserve by using this pattern. Casts are a way of telling the compiler to trust you, because you know some type information that it doesn't; in this case, you're simply taking a guess at the type, and getting it wrong.

Return Object, and check the type at the call site. Yes, it's going to be uglier; but ugly code is better than beautiful-but-broken code. The mere fact that you cast should give you pause to stop and consider what *might* go wrong here, rather than hiding it inside this method.

Comment: Right, that was exactly what I was getting. However, what I am trying to accomplish here is some way of checking the object type _inside_ the method, rather than checking at the call site of the method itself. Essentially, what I am looking to do is check if the retrieved object (returned from `getSetting`) is of the same type as the target object, specified (theoretically) by inferred type variable `T`. Is there another way of accomplishing this that I am unaware of? Or is this process simply asking too much of such a system?

Comment: @Michael that's simply not possible. The called method gets no information about the context in which the returned value (if any) will be used. The return type of a method is not part of its signature, so it's not even like you can work around it with overloads. All you can do is to have separate methods (e.g. `getFileSetting`, `getIntegerSetting`), and call the generic method/do the cast inside there; or provide a `Class<T>` (or similar) parameter, so that your generic method can check that the value matches.

Comment: I was afraid of that - but it's not like I wasn't expecting it. I got the information about type inference and type variable casting from an excerpt , as such: _"...The inference algorithm determines the types of the arguments and, if available, the type that the result is being assigned or returned. Finally, the inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type that works with all the arguments."_ However, if the return value's usage is not known at runtime, then I suppose I will have to fall back on manual casting. Thank you for your time and assistance regardless.